# Oracle loop in range by select query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table it likes below.

| id | start_range | end_range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pk1 | 202201 | 202204 |
| pk2 | 202202 | 202205 |
| pk3 | 202204 | 202209 |

What SQL in Oracle can help me get result likes below? Kindly help me out.

| id | perid |
| --- | --- |
| pk1 | 202201 |
| pk1 | 202202 |
| pk1 | 202203 |
| pk1 | 202204 |
| pk2 | 202202 |
| pk2 | 202203 |
| pk2 | 202204 |
| pk2 | 202205 |
| pk3 | 202204 |
| pk3 | 202205 |
| pk3 | 202206 |
| pk3 | 202207 |
| pk3 | 202208 |
| pk3 | 202209 |

Comment: And i found another way to approach it. 
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_loop_sql.htm

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it (i.e. with no explanation at all):

```
SQL> with test (id, start_range, end_range) as
  2    (select 'pk1', 202201, 202204 from dual union all
  3     select 'pk2', 202202, 202205 from dual union all
  4     select 'pk3', 202204, 202209 from dual
  5    )
  6  select id,
  7    start_range + column_value - 1 as perid
  8  from test cross join
  9    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                        connect by level <= end_range - start_range + 1
 11                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12  order by id, perid;

ID       PERID
--- ----------
pk1     202201
pk1     202202
pk1     202203
pk1     202204
pk2     202202
pk2     202203
pk2     202204
pk2     202205
pk3     202204
pk3     202205
pk3     202206
pk3     202207
pk3     202208
pk3     202209

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

But, if I had to guess, I'd say that start and end range represent months. If that's really so, code I posted above wouldn't work properly, but the one that follows will (as you have to deal with *dates* in that case):

```
SQL> with test (id, start_range, end_range) as
  2    (select 'pk1', 202201, 202204 from dual union all
  3     select 'pk2', 202210, 202302 from dual
  4    )
  5  select id,
  6    to_char(add_months(to_date(start_range, 'yyyymm'), column_value - 1), 'yyyymm') as perid
  7  from test cross join
  8    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                        connect by level <= months_between(to_date(end_range, 'yyyymm'),
 10                                                           to_date(start_range, 'yyyymm')) + 1
 11                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12  order by id, perid;

ID  PERID
--- ------
pk1 202201
pk1 202202
pk1 202203
pk1 202204
pk2 202210
pk2 202211
pk2 202212
pk2 202301
pk2 202302

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```